# With what probability does it come from the urn $U_3$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The urn $U_1$ contains $10$ red and $5$ green balls. The urn $U_2$ $3$ red and $7$ green, the urn $U_3$ $5$ red and $5$ green. Someone arbitrarily chooses a ball from one of the urns.

a) With what probability is the ball red?

b) The ball is red. With what probability does it come from the urn $U_3$?

$$$$

I have done the following:

a) $$P(r)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{10}{15}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{10}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{5}{10}$$

b) We want to calculate $P(U_3\mid r)=\frac{P(U_3\cap r)}{P(r)}$, or not? But what is the probability $P(U_3\cap r)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are being asked for $P(U_3|r)$.

\begin{align}
P(U_3 \cap r) &= P(r|U_3)P(U_3) \\
&= \frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac13
\end{align}

Note that

$$P(U_3|r) = \frac{P(r|U_3)P(U_3)}{P(r)}$$

is known as the Bayes' rule.

Comment: I see!! Thank you!!  :-)